# Using Countifs in excel with automatic range

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet that lists marines where in column G I have two values, trained and untrained. In column J the value is the unit the marine is with. I want to find the amount trained in each specific unit. Currently I am using `=countif(G2:G99,"TRAINED)` where g2:g99 is the range of marines in unit C, manually finding the range isn't hard, but I want to know if there is a way I can formulate countif that automatically finds the range based on the value in column J

hopefully my question is worded correctly and makes sense

Comment: you should include some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula below will give you the count of marines trained by unit on each line.

```
=Countifs(G:G,"Trained",J:J,J2) / COUNTIF(J:J, J2)
```

If you are putting this into a Summary view, just replace the J2 with the cell containing the Unit Name

Comment: Awesome, this is definitely helpful. Is there any way to make it show the percentage of trained vs. untrained? untrained is another possible value in column G. So say if the amount of trained marines in a unit is 72%, how would I get that to show?

Comment: You could divide by a another `COUNTIF` of the unit in column J.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot Table on this dataset to provide answers to various questions pretty quickly, if you aren't able to code these formulae in without some assistance.

It doesn't take time to understand it, basics can be found here: [Link](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-create-pivot-table-excel#sthash.IWiYWaIb.dpbs)

Once you have the pivot mapped out, drag "Marine Unit" column in rowlabel, then drag "Trained/Untrained" column in row label as well. You will start seeing the way table is shaping up. Drag "Trained/Untrained" again into Values this time.

You can use "Design tab on the top to play around with subtotals/totals, and field settings with count/sum/average/% of Total/etc. It might seem a bit complicated at start (atleast I did), but it really answers analytics Qns on the fly.